# Gtk set property from xml for a custom widget

Tags: python, gtk, gtk4

Let's say I make a custom widget with a property:

```
class MyWidget(Gtk.Box):
    __gtype_name__ = "MyWidget"
    
    my_property = GObject.Property(type=bool, default=False)

    ...
```

How can I set this property in the xml ?

```
...
<child>
    <object class="MyWidget">
        <property name="my_property">true</property>
    </object>
</child>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GObject.Property` as an annotation. You can add a setter as well:

```py
class MyWidget(Gtk.Box):
    __gtype_name__ = "MyWidget"
    
    @GObject.Property(type=bool, default=False)
    def my_property(self):
        return self._my_property

    @my_property.setter
    def set_my_property(self, value):
        self._my_property = value

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._my_property = False
```

Your original Builder UI will then work as expected.

More documentation is available [here](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/api/properties.html?highlight=property#GObject.Property).